# Total number of times a "Branch" column value repeated where "Status" column Value is "new"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to get the total number of times a "Branch" column value repeated where "Status" Value is "new"

Example:

```
+-----------------+
| Branch | Status |
+-----------------+
| XYZ    | New    |
+-----------------+
| ABC    | New    |
+-----------------+
| XYZ    | New    |
+-----------------+
| XYZ    | New    |
+-----------------+
| ABC    | New    |
+-----------------+
| ABC    | SOLVED |
+-----------------+
```

The printed result should be

```
XYZ: 3
ABC: 2
```

Comment: Needs a coding question to comply with rules. You can create a worksheet with the result you wish to email using a formula like =arrayformula(Unique(Sheet3!A2:A)&" count= "&countif(filter(Sheet3!A2:B,Sheet3!B2:B="New"),Unique(Sheet3!A2:A))) and then follow any of the email sample code examples

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved with a two native spreadsheet formulas. First list the unique "branches".

```
=Unique(A2:A)
```

Then count them with a `countif`. Let's say you placed the `unique` formula on cell `D2`, then you'd go:

```
=ArrayFormula(CountIf(A:A&"-"&B:B, D2&"-New"))
```

And then copy it down to all `unique` `continue` cells.

It can obviously also be done using Apps Script and even on a single `ArrayFormula`, which will be more complicated to read. And I don't think that's going to be helpful for you now.

Comment: Sounds good but I will have to do this in Google app scripts as I will have to calculate that and send an automated email once every 24 hours to the branch managers.

Comment: Have you tried out anything yet? Please post your code and where you're stuck then. You're not simply asking that we do it for you, are you? Anyway, the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) are a great start.